# Karma Runner > Loading bootstrap.js before angular and angular-mocks throws exception

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-runner

I have an angularjs app with some directives which make use of jquery and bootstrap components. So, in order to test the directives, I have defined the following order of files in karma.unit.conf.js:

```
files = [

 JASMINE,
 JASMINE_ADAPTER,

 'app/components/jquery/jquery.js',
 'app/scripts/vendor/bootstrap.js',

 'app/components/angular/angular.js',
 'app/components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
 'app/components/angular-ui/build/angular-ui.js',

 'app/scripts/app.js',

 'app/scripts/**/*.js',

 'test/spec/unit/**/*.js'

];
```

<strike>If I load first angularjs and angular-mocks and then jquery and bootstrap, the tests run and fail because angular uses its own jQLite. But if I change the order as I wrote up here then this is what I get:</strike>

## Edit:

I've found that it isn't jQuery what's causing the exception... it's bootstrap.js. If I comment the bootstrap.js line, the tests run (and fail, as expected because the bootstrap components never were loaded). If I load bootstrap as above (or in any other place before the tests) then I get this:

```
PhantomJS 1.8 (Linux) Directive: tkModal should make hidden element visible FAILED[39m
    at /home/ir/work/campari/app/components/jquery/jquery.js:1763
    at /home/ir/work/campari/app/components/jquery/jquery.js:2833
    at /home/ir/work/campari/app/components/jquery/jquery.js:2850
    at /home/ir/work/campari/app/components/jquery/jquery.js:2850
    at /home/ir/work/campari/app/components/jquery/jquery.js:2850
     ...
     at /home/ir/work/campari/app/components/jquery/jquery.js:2850
    at /home/ir/work/campari/app/components/jquery/jquery.js:2850
    at /home/ir/work/campari/app/components/jquery/jquery.js:2850
    at /home/ir/work/campari/app/components/jquery/jquery.js:3656
    at /home/ir/work/campari/app/components/jquery/jquery.js:648
    at /home/ir/work/campari/app/components/jquery/jquery.js:270
    at /home/ir/work/campari/app/components/jquery/jquery.js:3657
    at /home/ir/work/campari/app/components/jquery/jquery.js:3664
    at /home/ir/work/campari/app/components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1589
    at /home/ir/work/campari/app/components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1627
```

The line `at /home/ir/work/campari/app/components/jquery/jquery.js:2850` repeats endlessly about a 15k times before the test fails (it seems to be happening when jQuery tries to execute the internalData function at jquery.js:1763).

<strike>Any idea would be appreciated</strike>

## Edit: Solved

Found the answer, it was a bootstrap issue in version 2.3.0, updating to 2.3.1 solved it. See https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6835

Comment: If you've answered your own question, you should actually submit it as an answer to this question. That way, it won't show up in the 'unanswered' section ;-)

Comment: @TylerEich, at that time I wasn't able to post answers, I'll add it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, it was a bootstrap issue in version 2.3.0, updating to 2.3.1 solved it. See https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6835